# tabbed anchors simulating click

Tags: jquery, triggers, anchor

so I have this code for tabs in jquery, the href is set to about, what I want to do is provide a link in the menu that triggers this tab when clicked so http://myurl.com#about

```
$('#info-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $('#info div').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
 }).eq(0).addClass('current');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attach the handler to `<a>` element instead of `<li>`

```
$('#info-nav li a:first').click(function(e) {
    $('#info div').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');

    var clicked = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    e.preventDefault();

}).eq(0).closest('li').addClass('current');
```

so that on `DOMready` event I would read the hash in the URL (with `location.hash`) and I would trigger the `click` event (or the handler with `.triggerHandler()`) on the element whose href attribute is equal to that hash

```
$(function() {
    var hash = location.hash, tgt = $('a[href="' +  hash + '"]');
    if (hash !== '' && tgt.length) {
       tgt.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

call the same function on [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event (if the link you're providing is not actually changing the whole page)

```
$('window').bind('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = location.hash, tgt = $('a[href="' +  hash + '"]');
    if (hash !== '' && tgt.length) {
       tgt.trigger('click');
    }
});
```